Powershell: Create valid json file from object in array
I get all group names and the names of the "managedBy" field from AD. I want that output to export to an valid json file.
But my json isn't in a valid format, the brackets ([]) and the comma after each item are missing.
Can someone help me with that? What am I missing?
JSON file
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties name,managedBy |
ForEach-Object {
    $managedBy = $_.managedBy;
    if ($managedBy -ne $null){
        $managedByName = ($managedBy -split "," | ConvertFrom-StringData).CN 
    
        $managedByObject = Get-ADObject -Filter {Name -like $managedByName} | select Name, Objectclass
 
        If($managedByObject.ObjectClass -eq "user"){
            $manager = (get-aduser -Identity $managedBy -Properties displayName );
            $managerName = $manager.Name;
           
        }
        elseIf($managedByObject.ObjectClass -eq "group"){
            $managerName = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $managedByObject.Name | select Name) | ForEach-Object { $_.Name};
            $managerName=$managerName -join ';'
        }
    }
    else
    {
     $managerName = 'N/A';
    }    

    
    $output=[PSCustomObject]@{
        Name=$_.Name;
        ManagedBy=$managerName
    } 
    $outputjson = $output | ConvertTo-Json
    $outputjson | Add-Content -Path "C:\temp\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)-groupowners.json"

}


What is the current value of List separator? Control Panel > Select Region and Language > Formats Tab > Additional Settings

You’re outputting a separate json document for each AD group, which is why there’s no wrapping [ … ] or delimiting ,. If you want to output a single document containing a json array you first need to collect all the $output objects into an array, then convert that to json.

Instead of converting each output object to JSON 1 by 1, wait to convert to JSON until the end of your pipeline:
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties name,managedBy |
ForEach-Object {
    # ... forget about $output/$outputJson, simply output the object to the downstream pipeline commands (eg. ConvertTo-Json)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name=$_.Name;
        ManagedBy=$managerName
    } 
} |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content "C:\temp\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)-groupowners.json"

